# In app purchase consumable product responding error

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I am developing application with In app feature and need to purchase again and again according to need of user, but the application gets crash when we try to purchase product again with fallowing error message--`The original purchase must be reported as fulfilled before you can try to repurchase`
I tried using **ReportProductFulfillment(pID);** but not sure about the position to use this method,
please suggest me what to do?

Note-my product is consumable

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had you used this method?Please try this When receipt came from server(Windows Store).

ReportProductFulfillment(productId);

```
    // Summary:
    //     Notifies the marketplace that the application has delivered the paid-for
    //     goods to the user. You cannot repurchase a product until you have confirmed
    //     its delivery using this method
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   productId:
    //     The ID of the product that has been delivered to the user.
    public static void ReportProductFulfillment(string productId);
```